# same equation and same parameters why return different calculation results?

Tags: c++

I am using c++ to do some numeral calculations. I made some improvements to the function `coefficients_of_EnergyFunc(knots)`. But before and after the improvements, it returns the same parameters. Then I got different calculation results of `b` using these parameters. Why does this happen?

```cpp
    double* A = coefficients_of_EnergyFunc(knots);

    qDebug() << "A[1] = " << A[1] << endl;
    qDebug() << "A[3] = " << A[3] << endl;
    qDebug() << "A[4] = " << A[4] << endl;
    qDebug() << "A[6] = " << A[6] << endl;
    qDebug() << "A[7] = " << A[7] << endl;
    qDebug() << "A[8] = " << A[8] << endl;

    double b = A[1] - A[3] * A[7] / A[8] - A[4] * A[6] / A[8];

    qDebug() << "b = " << A[1] - A[3] * A[7] / A[8] - A[4] * A[6] / A[8] << endl;
```

The outputs before improvements:

```
A[1] =  572589 

A[3] =  39582.9 

A[4] =  32693.6 

A[6] =  19791.5 

A[7] =  32693.6 

A[8] =  3390.15 

b =  -8.73115e-11
```

The outputs after improvements:

```
A[1] =  572589 

A[3] =  39582.9 

A[4] =  32693.6 

A[6] =  19791.5 

A[7] =  32693.6 

A[8] =  3390.15 

b =  -0.0677077
```

By the way, substituting these parameters into the formula for calculating `b` in python console， I got:

```
>>> 572589 - 39582.9*32693.6 / 3390.15 - 32693.6*19791.5 / 3390.15
-0.0842116130515933
```

Comment: Can you post the output with `std::fixed` of all variables with `std::setprecision(15)`, after and before?

Comment: Your input `A[1]` has 0 digits of precision after the decimal point. Your "exact" result computed in python is two orders of magnitude below the error (as in insecurity) in your input. Could you explain what you expect any of these outputs should tell you?

Comment: try this qDebug() <<  qSetRealNumberPrecision(20) << b; Or for std try, std::coud << std::setprecision(20) << b;

Comment: Most likely the value of `A` is not the same before and after your change. They just appear to be when you print them because too few digits are printed. Make the following test: `A_old = oldFunction; A_new = newFunction; if (A_old[1] != A_new[1]) print_error_message; if (A_old[2] != A_new[2]) print_error_message; ....`

Comment: probably also makes sense to use the precision thing before printing all numbers, so you have the exact result

Comment: We don't know what improvements you made to the function.  Can you post the code of the function before and after?

Comment: If you've excluded the possibility the problem is related to precision, I wouldn't exclude the possibility that one of your improvements in the function is a bug - such as running past the end of an array.   Such things have a way of causing effects like that described here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `double* A = coefficients_of_EnergyFunc(knots);` returns other values than shown on the display. Since we do not know, what qDebug does exactly, we cannot really judge. But guess is that is rounds or shows only 1 digit for the fraction.

So, your new function (maybe also the old version) `coefficients_of_EnergyFunc(knots) has a bug`.

We cannot see this and help here. But thats a fact.

C++ calculates of course correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    double A1 = 572589;
    double A3 = 39582.9;
    double A4 = 32693.6;
    double A6 = 19791.5;
    double A7 = 32693.6;
    double A8 = 3390.15;

    double b = A1 - A3 * A7 / A8 - A4 * A6 / A8;
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It would have been really helpful if you would have shown all related function.

Comment: Yes，the function `coefficients_of_EnergyFunc(knots)` actually outputs different numbers before and after the modification but `qDebug()` only shows the part of the exact number.